# Can I bring gold sheet face masks in my carry on?

Tags: usa, airport-security, hand-luggage, tsa

[image: picture of the gold facemasks]
I have a few of these face masks individually sealed and wrapped. Can I bring these in my carry on as it contains a small amount of liquid to keep them wet? (similar to the way we can bring baby wipes?)

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely the TSA would prohibit these. Generally speaking, "moist" things are not restricted, only liquids. From the [TSA website](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all)

[image: wet wipes]

This sounds like it falls into that category.